# Kahan summation algorithm has big computing error when it is compiled by GCC

Tags: c++, algorithm, gcc

I use Kahan summation algorithm:

```
inline void KahanSum(float value, float & sum, float & correction)
{
    float term = value - correction;
    float temp = sum + term;
    correction = (temp - sum) - term;
    sum = temp; 
}

float KahanSum(const float * ptr, size_t size)
{
    float sum = 0, correction = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        KahanSum(ptr[i], sum, correction);
    return sum;
}
```

It works fine if it is compiled with using of MSVS, but it has a big computing error when I use GCC.

Where is the trouble here?

Comment: What do you mean by *big computing error when I use GCC*?  Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Show compiler flags and the produced assembly code

Comment: We can get the assembly code ourselves. What we really need, in order to be able to answer this question, is some sample inputs and the *expected outputs*. And the error message(s) that you're seeing, if any. Like, perhaps, you've forgotten to include the standard library header that defines `size_t`?

Comment: The Wiki page has a nice comment: "Beware overly-aggressive optimizing compilers!" Probably you should reduce optimization in this part of code.

Comment: [Works here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/86a5cdb7383412c3).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppouse, that it's a result of aggresive compiler optimization. So GCC can reduce the expression from:

```
    float term = value - correction;
    float temp = sum + term;
    correction = (temp - sum) - term;
    sum = temp;
```

to

```
    float term = value - correction;
    correction = 0;
    sum += term;
```

because this transformation is mathematically correct, but this optimization kills Kahan algorithm.

In order to avoid this problem you can use "-O1" GCC compiler options to compile the code. 
It will be something like this:

```
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#  pragma GCC push_options
#  pragma GCC optimize ("O1")
#endif 
inline void KahanSum(float value, float & sum, float & correction)
{
    float term = value - correction;
    float temp = sum + term;
    correction = (temp - sum) - term;
    sum = temp; 
}

float KahanSum(const float * ptr, size_t size)
{
    float sum = 0, correction = 0;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        KahanSum(ptr[i], sum, correction);
    return sum;
}
#if defined(__GNUC__)
#  pragma GCC pop_options
#endif
```

Comment: I see no evidence that GCC is doing the aggressive operations that you describe unless unsafe math optimizations are intentionally enabled (e.g., by throwing the `-ffast-math` switch). That isn't the default, even at -O3. It cannot be, as far as I know. There are strict rules about floating-point computations.

Comment: or use the "volatile" keyword on one of the variables, "temp" for example

Comment: @MayurPatel volatile does not work when using -ffast-math with g++ 10