# Is std::mutex enough for making all prior reads-writes happen before following reads-writes all in same thread?

Tags: c++, mutex, memory-fences

Does following function write to x[100] always before y[100] is written?

```
void fenceTest(float * x, float * y /* this could be x too*/)
{
    x[100]=3.14f; // maybe atomic write
    x[200]=3.14f;
    myMutex.lock();
    myMutex.unlock(); 
    y[100]=2.72f; // maybe atomic write too
    y[200]=2.72f;
}
```

or mutex needs to be unlocked after end point always even for this single-thread scenario or do we have to use atomic_thread_fence?

```
void fenceTest(float * x, float * y)
{
    x[100]=3.14f; // maybe atomic too
    x[200]=3.14f;
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    y[100]=2.72f; // maybe atomic write too
    y[200]=2.72f;
}
```

My intention is to tell both CPU and compiler that they are not allowed to reorder any load/store around the sync point so that all x-array operations are complete before any y-array operations begin.  I need to separate blocks of reads/writes so that an algorithm such as **Kahan-Summation** is not **broken by compiler's or CPU's reordering**.

Comment: I sense an XY-problem here. Is this about `x` and `y` pointing into the same array, or what?

Comment: *"Does following function write to x[100] always before y[100] is written?"* The implementation behaves as if it does - with or without intervening mutex operations. A single-threaded program won't be able to tell the difference. Why do you care?

Comment: Because X and Y not always pointing different arrays but also can be used in an error-reduction algorithm such as Kahan-Summation that uses additions and subtractions on same addresses sequently such that compiler can optimize all of them away and algorithm is broken.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik Well I'd say it's definitely XY problem. The issue if they're pointing to the same array is about 'aliasing' not memory synchronization. Forget about fences here. The compiler cannot assume that those expressions will point to different locations. Your problem shouldn't exist unless you have turned-on 'no pointer aliasing' in the compilation options (turn it off).

Comment: @Persixty What if everything is x? What  to do then? What if those writes are all atomics?

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik atomic vs non-atomic makes no sense in a single threaded program. A single threaded program always has sequential consistency (unless you have Undefined Behavior, but in that case *all* bets are off anyway).

Comment: @JesperJuhl I want to disable reordering per thread, not inter-thread. Could you look at Kahan Summation algorithm please? It is subject to cpu or compiler reordering and broken.

Comment: Compilers aren't generally allowed to reorder operations if that would change observable behavior. Some compilers have options to relax this rule for floating-point operations specifically (e.g. GCC's `-funsafe-math-optimizations`), because it may significantly improve performance and few programs care about getting very precise results. But if you don't enable such an option, the reordering you are concerned about shouldn't occur. Do you have evidence to the contrary?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik which is more compiler-migratable? floating-point flags in compiler options or using mutex/something_else only C++ code related instruction? Example of failing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37486225/kahan-summation-algorithm-has-big-computing-error-when-it-is-compiled-by-gcc

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik If they're atomics then they will take care of their own synchronization between threads and you still don't need them or to worry about them single threaded. You're over thinking this.

Comment: @Persixty I was asking about in-thread order. Does second atomic write start before first atomic by chance by cpu/compiler auto-optimization? I don't want these auto-optimizations and only between multiple blocks of codes, not whole functions(so compiler flag is not wanted).

Comment: If you are concerned with the behavior of a particular compiler, then test your approach on that compiler and see if it helps. If you are asking about what the C++ standard says, then it says that adding a mutex or a fence should make absolutely no difference to the observable behavior of your example.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik And what people are telling you is that it will make no difference. Memory fences and atomics only come into play in multi-threaded applications. Your worrying about something that doesn't exist. Even if you had an aliasing problem you shouldn't and probably couldn't solve it with fences or atomics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single-threaded application none of this matters, your program will see the reads and writes in the order you perform them, even if they don't actually happen in that order. This stuff only matters when the data is shared across multiple threads and cores.